# U_FILE_ACCESS_ERROR

Tags: r

I'm trying to set up R on a new computer at work, and having trouble. Most of my packages load just fine, but a few packages reliably give a "U_FILE_ACCESS_ERROR" message when I try to load them. For example, when I enter:

> library(lmerTest)

I get the following:

> Loading required package: Matrix
>
> Loading required package: lme4
>
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘lmerTest’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
>
> ICU init failed: U_FILE_ACCESS_ERROR

And I get the same error messages for Hmisc, htmltable, stringr, evaluate, and rmarkdown.

I've made sure I have the latest version of R and of the packages themselves, and I've tried deleting and re-installing the packages. I'm not sure what else to do. Thank you for any help you can offer!

Comment: The alleged duplicate answer suggests to reinstall A LOT of packages which may or may not be the cause... I would suggest to start with the package `stringi` as it wraps the [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) library for R so the error might come from there.